# array 2D JSON get into android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I have the next array by a php file into the server:

```
 {
    "Id": [
        "2",
        "3",
        "5"
    ],
    "Nombre": [
        "PRj1",
        "PRj2",
        "PRj3"
    ],
    "Imagen": [
        "http://kcfinder/upload/imagenes/proyectos/2/portada.jpg",
        "http://kcfinder/upload/imagenes/proyectos/3/portada.jpg",
        "http://kcfinder/upload/imagenes/proyectos/5/portada.jpg"
    ]
}
```

I need extract the info for make the next arrays:

```
String [] Id,Nombre,Imagen;
```

How can i get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking, please try to make your question more clear. Give example inputs and outputs

Comment: Thx RobVoisey, and sorry for do a duplicate answerd